Cron to fire function in WordPress Plugin - wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment not loading images
Currently the function will complete with out problems via a button on the admin side / plugin folder.
Products information updates as expected but the image fails only via Cron, Throwing internal error:
$image_url = wc_rest_upload_image_from_url( $pic_url_r,$pro_id);
$image_id1 = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($image_url, $pro_id);

The Error
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-rest-functions.php:135

thrown in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-rest-functions.php on line 135

The error lands at function:
function wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment? (dont have permission via cron)



The cron only works if i am logged in browser, How am I able to include those wp-admin functions for cron to have access?.
**Dumped ERROR: **

Array ( [woocommerce_rest_invalid_image] => Array ( [0] => Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.



What exactly are you executing via cron? And where is the value for that variable supposed to come from?

I am updating images via Cron , I have checked the variable its empty only whilst  Cron calls function but works in admin area plugin if i was to call function via btn. I'm thinking its permission issue. Cron as its own user does not have access to all woo commerce  functions. Im not sure how to allow Cron to have the same access as such.

wc_rest_upload_image_from_url went wrong, so $image_url is an instance of WP_Error not. Please dump that object, to see if it contains any more details about what actually went wrong.

@CBroe updated thanks

Permissions was the reason admin functions are not working as expected. Cron was not logged in technically. Work around was to emulate user with permissions during Cron. Setup a user in WP admin section with the right access.
steps :
create cron.php file
Command Cron :   */30 * * * curl https://example.com/cron.
We want to access Cron.php as a webpage with the same environment as such, not direct.
    //cron will need to include

    wp-config.php 
    wp-load.php

    //https://gist.github.com/digisavvy/0cd5c8023105c17679811014b9decc7d
    login(){
       myfunction();
    }

  

Automated wp login example script found here:
https://gist.github.com/digisavvy/0cd5c8023105c17679811014b9decc7d
Tailor the script in your cron.php as you need.
log out after function complete.
Result is to run admin functions from Cron in WordPress.
